# It is possible to combine http/rest contracts with amqp?

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-contract

currently I have a system with a REST API but that also publishes rabbitmq messages to another system.

Currently I have separate groovy files with contracts for both http and amqp, but I wish to do this in one single file. That is, I am able to check that the http request/response to the API works fine but I cannot check if the amqp message was published. I have to create an extra groovy file with the contract that sends the data to the controller with the same input as the previous test and that checks that the message is indeed published.

So currently I have one groovy file like this for the REST part:

```
Contract.make {
    name("http_event_with_valid_token")
    description ('A event is received with a valid token.')
    request {
        method 'POST'
        url '/events/token'
        headers {
            contentType(applicationJson())
        }
        body("""
            {
                "parameter": "value"
            }
        """)
    }
    response {
        status 202
    }
}
```

And another for the AMQP part:

```
Contract.make {
    name("amqp_event_with_valid_token")
    description( "A event is received with a valid token.")
    input {
        triggeredBy('controller.event("token", "{\\"parameter\\":\\"value\\"}")')
    }
    outputMessage {
        sentTo 'exchange.events.events'
        body("""
            {
                "parameter": "value"
            }
        """)
        headers {
            header('token': 'token')
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to do both checks in one single groovy file, without generating two separate tests. Is this possible?

Comment: I forgot to mention but I am using Spring cloud contract

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use single test/test suite with parameters then I would recommend reading up `[Spock Framework][1]`. It lets you execute same test with multiple arguments (i.e.parameters).

You might have to change your code a bit for this, but an example would look like this:

```
class HelloSpockSpec extends Specification {
  def "length of Spock's and his friends' names"() {
    expect:
    name.size() == length

    where:
    name     | length
    "Spock"  | 5
    "Kirk"   | 4
    "Scotty" | 6
  }
}
```

You can define multiple elements of the contracts, keep the structure same and check the response status in your groovy file defined in question (e.g. You can pass name, description, request from the parameters).

[Here](https://github.com/spockframework/spock-example/tree/master/src/test/groovy) are some examples.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am using Spring Cloud Contract, my idea is to combine the HTTP call/request verification with the amqp message publish to an external system in the same test/groovy file.